# How to set the maxAllowedContentLength to 500MB while running on IIS7?

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, file-upload, .net-4.0

I changed the maxAllowedContentLength to

```
<security>
    <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="5024000000" />
    </requestFiltering>
</security>
```

In my web.config, but when running on IIS7 I get this error:

> The 'maxAllowedContentLength' attribute is invalid. Not a valid unsigned integer

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/u1ZFe.jpg]

but when I run in the VS server it run normally without any errors.

How to config my website to allow upload files with 500MB size, without this problem on IIS7?

Comment: 5024000000 (let me add thousand separators) 5.024.000.000 is larger than the maximum unsigned int 4.294.967.295, you are looking for 502.400.000 as the value in ur config instead (without the thousand separators)

Answer (score 105, accepted):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms689462%28VS.90%29.aspx) `maxAllowedContentLength` has type `uint`, its [maximum value](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x0sksh43.aspx) is 4,294,967,295 bytes = 3,99 gb

So it should work fine.

See also [Request Limits article](http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.webServer/security/requestFiltering/requestLimits). Does IIS return one of these errors when the appropriate section is not configured at all?

See also: [Maximum request length exceeded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3853767/maximum-request-length-exceeded/)

Comment: so this value i have 5024000000 is by gb?!

Comment: 500MB = 524288000 which is now less than 4294967295

Answer (score 205):

The limit of requests in .Net can be configured from two properties together:

### First

- `Web.Config/system.web/httpRuntime/maxRequestLength` (in kilobytes)
- Unit of measurement: kilobytes
- Default value 4096 KB (4 MB)
- Max. value 2147483647 KB (2 TB; older IIS may be limited to 2097151 KB, aka around 2 GB)

### Second

- `Web.Config/system.webServer/security/requestFiltering/requestLimits/maxAllowedContentLength`  (in bytes)
- Unit of measurement: bytes
- Default value 30000000 bytes (28.6 MB)
- Max. value 4294967295 bytes (4 GB)

References:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/security/requestfiltering/requestlimits/#attributes
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.configuration.httpruntimesection.maxrequestlength

Example:

```
<location path="upl">
   <system.web>
     <!--The default size is 4096 kilobytes (4 MB). MaxValue is 2147483647 KB (2 TB)-->
     <!-- 100 MB in kilobytes -->
     <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="102400" />
   </system.web>
   <system.webServer>
     <security>
       <requestFiltering>          
         <!--The default size is 30000000 bytes (28.6 MB). MaxValue is 4294967295 bytes (4 GB)-->
         <!-- 100 MB in bytes -->
         <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="104857600" />
       </requestFiltering>
     </security>
   </system.webServer>
 </location>
```

Comment: Very helpful, however I believe that the max value for maxAllowedContentLength is roughly 4 GB, not 4 TB

Comment: The article says "Specifies the maximum length of content in a request, in bytes.". Means both config keys use BYTES making max request size same, 4GB.

Comment: @abatishchev The other config key, the httpRuntime maxRequestLength one, is specified in kilobytes, not bytes. The requestLimits maxAllowContentLength one is specified in just bytes.

Answer (score 21):

**IIS v10** (but this should be the same also for IIS 7.x)

**Quick addition for people which are looking for respective max values**

Max for `maxAllowedContentLength` is: `UInt32.MaxValue` 
 `4294967295 bytes` : `~4GB`

Max for `maxRequestLength` is: `Int32.MaxValue`  `2147483647 bytes` : `~2GB`

**web.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <!-- ~ 2GB -->
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2147483647" />
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <!-- ~ 4GB -->
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="4294967295" />
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Changing "httpRuntime maxRequestLength" is not a good practice (DoS), you need to change is "requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength"  [configuring aspnet and iis request length for post data](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2016/apr/06/configuring-aspnet-and-iis-request-length-for-post-data)

Comment: -1 for incorrectly usng maxRequestLength. It is specifid in kilobytes, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.configuration.httpruntimesection.maxrequestlength?view=netframework-4.8