# IIS7 - The request filtering module is configured to deny a request that exceeds the request content length

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, iis, iis-7

I want to upload images, it works fine on my machine but when I put my website on IIS7 server for public I can't upload anything.

### Error

> The request filtering module is configured to deny a request that
>   exceeds the request content length.

### Most likely causes

> Request filtering is configured on the Web server to deny the request
>   because the content length exceeds the configured value.

### Things you can try

> Verify the configuration/system.webServer/security/requestFiltering/requestLimits@maxAllowedContentLength
>   setting in the applicationhost.config or web.config file.

### system.webServer in Web.config

```
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
         <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="1048576" />
      </requestFiltering>
   </security>
  </system.webServer>
```

As you can see I set my maxAllowedContentLength to 1gb. Restarted my website and still getting this error. I made an `/uploads/` folder on my file system where it suppose to be as well. Have no idea what causes this error and why I can't upload images.

Comment: maxAllowedContentLength is in bytes. You've set a 1MB limit. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms689462%28VS.90%29.aspx

Comment: Latest MSDN documentation is in KB: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.httpruntimesection.maxrequestlength(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 50, accepted):

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="1048576" />
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3853767/maximum-request-length-exceeded).

For IIS7 and above, you also need to add the lines below:

```
 <system.webServer>
   <security>
      <requestFiltering>
         <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="1073741824" />
      </requestFiltering>
   </security>
 </system.webServer>
```

Comment: you are missing half the story.. you need to configure also **MaxAllowedContentLength**

Comment: @LaPuyaLoca is correct, this is half an answer, I think the full one is provided [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40085473/2912011).

Answer (score 3):

*The following example Web.config file will configure IIS to deny access for HTTP requests where the length of the "Content-type" header is greater than 100 bytes.*

```
  <configuration>
   <system.webServer>
      <security>
         <requestFiltering>
            <requestLimits>
               <headerLimits>
                  <add header="Content-type" sizeLimit="100" />
               </headerLimits>
            </requestLimits>
         </requestFiltering>
      </security>
   </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Source: http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/security/requestfiltering/requestlimits

Comment: could you please explain what you did to fix the issue?

Comment: I don't know how, but this solution worked for me. I was having configuration error saying: `HTTP Error 404.7 - Not Found. The request filtering module is configured to deny the file extension.` while trying to run existing `wcf` project in `Role` of new `Azure Cloud Service`. I added these lines in `web.config` of existing `wcf` project, and it worked

Comment: @zeeshan I wouldn't spend too much time troubleshooting Azure server configs.... There are some other gotchas.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue, I resolved by changing the requestlimits maxAllowedContentLength ="40000000" section of applicationhost.config file, located in "C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config" directory

Look for security Section and add the sectionGroup.

```
<sectionGroup name="requestfiltering">
    <section name="requestlimits" maxAllowedContentLength ="40000000" />
</sectionGroup>
```

***NOTE** delete;

```
<section name="requestfiltering" overrideModeDefault="Deny" />
```

Comment: This method is not helpful at all. When I delete as your note the file applicationhost.config ran into error

Answer (score 0):

***I used it like this and it worked for me  :***

*Added this in web.config*

```
 <security>
  <requestFiltering>
    <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="1073741824" />
  </requestFiltering>
</security>
```

*Also added this on my controller's method*

```
    [RequestFormLimits(MultipartBodyLengthLimit = 1073741824)]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Upload(IFormFile file)
    {
        // file code here
    }
```