# How to change the maxAllowedContentLength of IIS 7.0?

Tags: asp.net, iis-7

Ii have a problem similar to: [How to set the maxAllowedContentLength to 500MB while running on IIS7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4022434/how-to-set-the-maxallowedcontentlength-to-500mb-while-running-on-iis7)

The difference is that I have already modified my `web.config` to accept files upto 2 Gb in size but when try and upload a large file, I get the following error:

> The request filtering module is configured to deny a request that exceeds the length of the content.

my `web.config` is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <httpRuntime executionTimeout="999999" maxRequestLength="2097151"/>
        <customErrors mode="Off"/>      
        <compilation debug="true" strict="false" explicit="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
            <membership>
            <providers>
            <clear/>
            </providers>
        </membership>
        <profile>
            <providers>
            <clear/>

            </providers>
        </profile>
        <roleManager enabled="false">
            <providers>
            <clear/>

            </providers>
        </roleManager>
</system.web>
<system.webServer>
    <security>
        <requestFiltering>
            <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="2097151" />
        </requestFiltering>
    </security>
</system.webServer>
```

I still receive the error when i try to upload a file that it is only `131 MB`.

So, what should I set in the `maxAllowedContentLength` settings to allow people to upload files over 100 MB please?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

While [`MaxRequestLength`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.httpruntimesection.maxrequestlength.aspx) is number of *kilobytes*, [`maxAllowedContentLength`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms689462%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) is number of *bytes*. Multiply it again by 1024, and it should work fine.

> **maxAllowedContentLength**
>   Optional uint attribute.
>   Specifies the maximum length of content in a
>   request, in bytes.
>   The default value is 30000000.
>   <sub>[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms689462(v=vs.90).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms689462%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)</sub>

Comment: your right i even read about that it is in byte and i still ignored sorry for the sally question, but thank you for the answer

Answer (score 3):

Type **inetmgr** in windows Run (WinKey + r)
click your server name on left panel and in right panel in **IIS** section double click Request Filtering. on the rightest panel click **Edit Feature Settings...** . In **Request Limits** section you can change the **maxAllowedContentLength**.

If you want change **maxAllowedContentLength** just in one of your sites, on the left panel select your site under **Sites** and go the same way as above to change it.