# Setting uploadReadAheadSize in IIS 8.5

Tags: iis, iis-8, windows-server-2012-r2

I'm trying to use the following command to set uploadReadAheadSize in IIS 8.5 on Windows Server 2012 R2:

```
appcmd.exe set config -section:system.webServer/serverRuntime/uploadReadAheadSize:"491521"  /commit:apphost
```

But I keep getting this error:

```
ERROR ( message:Can not set attribute "uploadReadAheadSize" to value "491521 ".. 
Reason: Not a valid unsigned integer . )
```

From [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525310%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) the maximum should be 4GB so my integer is valid. (Admittedly this goes back to IIS 6.0 so not sure how relevant it is now.)

[This page](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/serverruntime) on the other hand suggests that the property may have been replaced/deprecated or something, but it's not clear from the error message or anything I can find on the Googles.

I'm no expert in IIS so there may be a simple/obvious answer to this, but I'd be grateful if anyone can share some more concrete info...

UPDATE: [also posted in IIS forums](http://forums.iis.net/p/1208166/2071127.aspx?p=True&t=635303109910129547&pagenum=1)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

- Open IIS
- Navigate under Default Web Site
- Scroll down to Management and open Configuration Editor
- Select following section (drop down at the top) **system.webServer** and expand it, then locate serverRuntime
- you'll find there the current value of uploadReadAheadSize value, which you can change

Answer (score 11):

Four years later... The clue was in the error message: "491521 " is not a valid unsigned integer. Note the space at the end of the integer before the quote marks.

Turns out the command I was running had a double space between the value and the /commit. Change to a single space and the command works fine.

Interestingly it's the same command I've been using for years and I've just confirmed it still works fine with the double space in Server 2008 R2!

Answer (score 3):

[How to set the maxAllowedContentLength to 500MB while running on IIS7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4022434/how-to-set-the-maxallowedcontentlength-to-500mb-while-running-on-iis7)

Try this.  Looks like you need to set it below 4294967295(in bytes)

Comment: Don't post links to solutions, post the solution. Links go dead.

Comment: Vikrant, my integer is 491521. As I said, it should be below the limit already.

Comment: 4294967294 is invalid. Instead, 2147483647 (int.max) is accepted. Just shy of 2gb.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
appcmd.exe set config  -section:system.webServer/serverRuntime /uploadReadAheadSize:"491521" /commit:apphost
```

There must be a space after `-section:system.webServer/serverRuntime` and before `/uploadReadAheadSize` .

Answer (score 1):

[WebServer Run Time](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/serverruntime)

```
POWERSHELL Command
Set-WebConfigurationProperty -pspath 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST'  -filter "system.webServer/serverRuntime" -name "uploadReadAheadSize" -value 2147483647

uploadReadAheadSize Optional uint attribute.
```

Specifies the number of bytes that a Web server will read into a buffer and pass to an `ISAPI` extension or module. This occurs once per client request. The `ISAPI` extension or module receives any additional data directly from the client. The value must be between 0 and 2147483647.

The default value is 49152.