# Web.Config problem: This configuration section cannot be used at this path

Tags: asp.net-core, iis, iis-express, applicationhost

I need to set `uploadReadAheadSize` attribute of `serverRuntime` element in ASP.NET Core `web.config`, but after launching, it throws a HTTP Error 500.19 with the message

> This configuration section cannot be used at this path

I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54450447/iis-express-applicationhost-config-authentication-error), that I just need to set `overrideModeDefault` to "Allow" for `ServerRuntime` in `{ProjectDirectory}.vs\\config\\applicationhost.config` path. And that's exactly the problem, because everyone on the team has to change this setting locally the first time they run the application.

We could also add an applicationhost file in `.gitignore`, but we would like to avoid this.

Are there any options so that I don't have to change `applicationhost.config` every time I start the project for the first time? My goal is to make the first launch of an application a little easier for developers.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Create new ASP.NET Core Web API
2. Create Web.Config with:

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <serverRuntime uploadReadAheadSize="1000000" />
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

3. Run app using IISExpress

Comment: Based on my searching and testing, this doesn't seem to be possible, and also when running the app for the first time.

Comment: Take a look at [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22230458/setting-uploadreadaheadsize-in-iis-8-5).

Comment: That's a thing you feel like a problem, but Microsoft considers a feature (to harden the system and prevent security risks). Thus, the answer is simply no other options like you found.