# The page was not displayed because the request entity is too large.When Download a 10Gb ZIP file

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, iis-7

While Downloading large zip file size is 10GB using c#. i am getting error like 
'The page was not displayed because the request entity is too large.' 
already i am given the app command in iis and

```
  appcmd.exe set config -section:system.webserver/serverruntime /uploadreadaheadsize: 1048576   /commit:apphost
```

and i have changed the config file

```
    <system.serviceModel>
     <bindings>
       <basicHttpBinding>
         <binding maxReceivedMessageSize="10485760">
          <readerQuotas ... />
      </binding>
       </basicHttpBinding>
     </bindings>  
   </system.serviceModel>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`maxReceivedMessageSize` is in bytes.

You specified 10MB instead of 10GB, you could change it to `10 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024`:

```
 <binding maxReceivedMessageSize="10737418240">
```

But that won't work [due to a limit as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4022434/how-to-set-the-maxallowedcontentlength-to-500mb-while-running-on-iis7).

Comment: hi i given  appcmd.exe set config -section:system.webserver/serverruntime /uploadreadaheadsize:12884901888  /commit:apphost but i am getting error

Comment: @thumbunkeys:C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv>appcmd.exe set config "SCS WEB 1234" -section:system
.webServer/serverRuntime /uploadReadAheadSize:"12884901888" /commit:apphost
ERROR ( message:Can not set attribute "uploadReadAheadSize" to value "1288490188
8".. Reason: Not a valid unsigned integer
. )

Comment: a simple search for the error message yielded this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4022434/how-to-set-the-maxallowedcontentlength-to-500mb-while-running-on-iis7

Comment: if i have 10gb file means how can i download