# SonarQube 5.6.1 report upload fail if size > 20 megabytes 404 error code

Tags: tomcat, tfs, sonarqube, sonar-runner, sonarqube-scan

I successfully setup a sonar qube instance with a team foundation server/vNext on windows server. *this is a different problem then sqube 6.0/6.1 and the connectorj problem.

Some of our projects generate reports of size greater than 20 megabytes and at upload time we get a 404 error from sonar qube. Since all other projects works fine and only those who generate > 20m reports, I suspect the maxPostSize param in Tomcat but everything is embedded in .jars so I'm not sure how to double check it. In github, the connector seems correctly set to -1 (infinite post size). In the mbean descriptor of tomcat (org/apache/catalina/connector/mbeans-descriptors.xml), the attribute max post size is defined but without a default value.

Error in question :

```
Analysis reports compressed in 15547ms, zip size=34 MB

EXECUTION FAILURE
Total time: 13:56.691s
Final Memory: 67M/574M
Error during SonarQube Scanner execution


org.sonarqube.ws.client.HttpException: Error 404 on https://sonarqube.company.com/api/ce/submit?projectKey=good_project_key&projectName=good_project_name

[error]at org.sonarqube.ws.client.BaseResponse.failIfNotSuccessful(BaseResponse.java:34)
[error]at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.BatchWsClient.failIfUnauthorized(BatchWsClient.java:99)
[error]at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.BatchWsClient.call(BatchWsClient.java:69)
[error]at org.sonar.batch.report.ReportPublisher.upload(ReportPublisher.java:172)
```

Comment: for sure the default configuration supports reports that are a few hundreds MB. Is there a proxy in front of web server ?

Comment: yes thx that was it.

Answer (score 11):

You seem to be using an HTTPS URL for your SonarQube, which means that you're contacting it through a reverse-proxy. Since you're on Windows then (I guess) you might be using Microsoft IIS, in which case double-check your [file upload limits in IIS](http://ajaxuploader.com/large-file-upload-iis-asp-net.htm).

If another proxy: double-check its file upload limits likewise.

Comment: That was the problem.

in the web.config 
      <requestFiltering>
        <!-- 50MB in bytes, default is 30000000 or approx. 28.6102 Mb-->
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="52428800" /> 
      </requestFiltering>
<system.web>
    <!-- 50MB in kilobytes, default is 4096 or 4MB-->
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="51200" />
  </system.web>

for info on those flags : 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4022434/how-to-set-the-maxallowedcontentlength-to-500mb-while-running-on-iis7

Comment: Cool. You should [accept](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) this answer if it solved your problem.