# Web.config settings not working to accept file size with more than 1 gb

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, file-upload

I am trying to upload csv file with size **1.10 gb** and i would like to allow user to upload file up to size **10 gb**.

**Web.config settings** :

```
<system.web>
    <authentication mode="None" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="10240000" targetFramework="4.5" /> <!-- this will file upload up to 10 gb-->
  </system.web>
 <system.webServer>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="10240000" /><!-- iis setting to handle file upload up to 10 gb-->
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
    <modules>
      <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
```

**Error**:[image]

Above settings are based on [this reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/288612/how-to-increase-the-max-upload-file-size-in-asp-net).

I am using [ng-File Upload](https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload) to upload file to server.

Comment: can you check this link please.
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4022434/how-to-set-the-maxallowedcontentlength-to-500mb-while-running-on-iis7][1]

Answer (score 3):

Increase the value of `maxAllowedContentLength`. Maximum value of `maxAllowedContentLength` is 4,294,967,295 bytes = 3,99 gb.

Answer (score 2):

You can set it to 3.99 GB max. According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms689462(VS.90).aspx) `maxAllowedContentLength` has type [uint](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x0sksh43.aspx), its maximum value is 4,294,967,295 bytes = 3.99 GB