# What is the maximum value for "maxAllowedContentLength" in IIS 7.5?

Tags: .net, web-config, iis-7.5

What is the maximum value for **maxAllowedContentLength** in a Web.config file having a Windows Server 2008 R2 and IIS 7.5?

> ```
>   <system.webServer>
>     <security>
>       <requestFiltering>
>         <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="???"/>
>       </requestFiltering>
>     </security>
>   </system.webServer>
> ```

Comment: take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4022434/how-to-set-the-maxallowedcontentlength-to-500mb-while-running-on-iis7

Answer (score 2):

The comment above obviously showed where to find the answer.

Another source is to check IIS schema files, which locates usually at `%windir%\system32\inetsrv\config\schema` folder

https://github.com/lextm/iis_schema/blob/master/IIS_schema.xml#L1321