# WebAPI 3.2.0.0 - Need to accept huge data upto 5MB as input and save (GET)

Tags: c#, .net, api, webapi

Please help me to work on WebAPI - Need to accept huge data up-to 5MB as input and save (GET). how to enable this feature in API.

Environment: Microsoft.Net, C#

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set the maxAllowedContentLength to 500MB while running on IIS7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4022434/how-to-set-the-maxallowedcontentlength-to-500mb-while-running-on-iis7)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the max size of the file is about `4MB (4096 KB)`, so you need to change the default value size by custom size. You need to change the value of `httpRuntime maxRequestLength` in your `web.config` file. following code for setting `2GB`.

```
<system.web>
  <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2097152" />
</system.web>
```

Read more about it here:
[Dealing with large files in ASP.NET](https://www.strathweb.com/2012/09/dealing-with-large-files-in-asp-net-web-api/)